# d3.js not returning a dynamically constructed html element on append

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I am making a treemap in d3.js, and I need it to append labels which contain dynamic html taking data from multiple nodes in my JSON. Here is the basic append I am trying to do:

```
childBody.append('p').attr("class", "label")
.html(function(d) {
    return d.name + "<span>" + d.size + "</span>";
});
```

but when I do this only the d.name is appended (the p tag, without the span), in other words:

```
<body class="labelbody"><p class="label">[d.name]</p></body>
```

Here is the only way I've found to append multiple items, but it's not nested, so the size is not within the "label"

tag, so it won't display properly.

```
childBody.append('p').attr("class", "label")
.text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
});

childBody.append('p').text(function(d) {
    return d.size;
});
```

resulting in:

```
<body class="labelbody"><p class="label">jQuery</p><p>90</p></body>
```

I am adapting my example from this

http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/wp-content/js/treemap_headers_03.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the p tag so you can append to it rather than appending some other p tag.

```
var p = childBody.append('p').attr("class", "label").text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
});

p.append('span').text(function(d) {
    return d.size;
});
```

or you could do it in one go via

```
childBody.append('p').attr("class", "label").text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
}).append('span').text(function(d) {
    return d.size;
});
```